# Writing XML file to android after appending it

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm need to write the XML file in android and replace it with the new one. The code is working properly but nothing changed in the XML file I have.

any ideas?

```
try{

FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("/data/data/test.fileshow/files/Landmarks.xml", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 
String filepath = "Landmarks.xml";

DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);
     Element Row, Longitude, Latitude, Title, Category, Rating;

            Node staff = doc.getElementsByTagName("Root").item(0);

         Row=doc.createElement("Row");
         Longitude=doc.createElement("Longitude");
         Longitude.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("555"));
         Row.appendChild(Longitude);
         Latitude=doc.createElement("Latitude");
         Latitude.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("ABCCamera"));
         Row.appendChild(Latitude);
         Title=doc.createElement("Title");
         Title.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("title"));
         Row.appendChild(Title);
         Category=doc.createElement("Category");
         Category.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("category"));
         Row.appendChild(Category);
         Rating=doc.createElement("Rating");
         Rating.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("rating"));
         Row.appendChild(Rating);
         staff.appendChild(Row);


        //write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result =  new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        osw.flush();
        osw.close();

      }catch(ParserConfigurationException pce){
     pce.printStackTrace();
      }catch(TransformerException tfe){
     tfe.printStackTrace();
      }catch(IOException ioe){
     ioe.printStackTrace();
      }catch(SAXException sae){
     sae.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: If you indent the code, people will be more able and willing to help you.

Comment: You initialize, flush and close 'osw', but never actually write anything to it.

Comment: i did try the osw.write() but i don't know how to get the results. I needed someone to show me how to write the results out to the file in android. Thanks for editting the code view thanathos =)

Answer (score 1):

I was having issues writing DOM documents and this set me on the right path.  From your code, I had to bind the OutputStreamWriter to the StreamResult.

After you instantiate:

```
StreamResult result =  new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
```

call the following:

```
result.setWriter(osw);
```

before performing the transform.  This worked for me.

Comment: Not only did this solution fix that problem, but a dozen other bugs as well! Thanks, dbennett63!