#  malformed url exception:protocol not found  while adding or deleting data from xml in android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I have given the sample of an xml I am using  to get the list of food items and inflating it to the list view.while I try to add the item to my xml file at runtime I am getting url malformed exception.may be the path I am giving is not valid.I have put my xml in package/res/raw/testcalory.xml.kindly help.

EXCEPTION:12-26 14:35:58.516: WARN/System.err(11597): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: testcalory.xml

```
//sample xml
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <company>
        <Row>
                <Item_Name>Aam Ras </Item_Name>
                <CalorieContentPerGram>1.12</CalorieContentPerGram>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Item_Name>Akuri </Item_Name>
                <CalorieContentPerGram>1.62</CalorieContentPerGram>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Item_Name>Almond ICC </Item_Name>
                <CalorieContentPerGram>5.35</CalorieContentPerGram>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Item_Name>Almond Milkshake </Item_Name>
                <CalorieContentPerGram>1.16</CalorieContentPerGram>
        </Row>
    </company>


    //sample code
   private void addItem() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{

            FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("testcalory", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 
            String filepath = "testcalory.xml";

            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                 DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                 Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);
                 org.w3c.dom.Element Row;
                org.w3c.dom.Element Item_Name;
                org.w3c.dom.Element CalorieContentPerGram;

                        Node company = doc.getElementsByTagName("company").item(0);

                     Row=doc.createElement("Row");

                     Item_Name=doc.createElement("Item_Name");
                     Item_Name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("hulala"));
                     Row.appendChild(Item_Name);

                     CalorieContentPerGram=doc.createElement("CalorieContentPerGram");
                     CalorieContentPerGram.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("556"));
                     Row.appendChild(CalorieContentPerGram);
                     company.appendChild(Row);


                    //write the content into xml file
                    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                    StreamResult result =  new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
                    transformer.transform(source, result);

                    result.setWriter(osw);
                    osw.flush();
                    osw.close();

                  }catch(ParserConfigurationException pce){
                 pce.printStackTrace();
                  }catch(TransformerException tfe){
                 tfe.printStackTrace();
                  }catch(IOException ioe){
                 ioe.printStackTrace();
                  }catch(SAXException sae){
                 sae.printStackTrace();
                  }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case it will not work. You should read about xml parsers and writers. For instance, [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/).

As for me I used once [Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/). It is really simple and allows you to parse and create xml files from your application.

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591678/writing-xml-file-to-android-after-appending-it>.I saw this and I think that it can solve my problem,but don't know where to put my  sample.xml initialy so that I can over write its contents.do I have to make a new folder in my project and place sample.xml there because I think I am quite close but getting urlmalformed exception may be because emulator is unable to locate my path for the xml..